# (Implemented) algorithm for Hodge numbers

Tags: hodge-theory, toric-varieties, mathematical-software

Let $X$ be a smooth projective toric variety. Do any of the math computer algebra systems have an algorithm implemented to compute the Hodge numbers of a generic complete intersection in $X$? Say in terms of the combinatorics used to encode divisors.

Even more basic, how about for hypersurfaces in a given ample class? i.e. given an integral polytope, it would output the Hodge polynomial.

If not, why not? Is an algorithm too difficult to implement? Or are there still unknowns involved, e.g. ranks of various maps of cohomology spaces in long exact sequences?

Comment: If you have a clear idea how the algorithm should work, then you may just implement it yourself. Something not being implemented doesn't always mean it's difficult, either technically or theoretically. Might be just not enough motivation.

Comment: Looks like Macaulay can compute Hodge numbers:  https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_hh.html